# ionic 2 - Inappbrowser event fire after second call

Tags: ionic2, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I use inappbrowser plugin in ionic 2 application like this :

```
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
```

and use it like this :

```
launch(url){
      this.browser = new InAppBrowser( url, "_blank", "EnableViewPortScale=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done" );
      this.browser.on("exit")
          .subscribe(
              () => {
                this.close_event=true;
              },
              err => {
                console.log("InAppBrowser Loadstop Event Error: " + err);
              });
  }
```

and in html :

```
<button  ion-button icon-right color="danger"  (click)="launch('https://www.example.com')">launch
    <ion-icon name="refresh"></ion-icon>
```

when click on `launch button` for first time and after close browser, `exit event` not fire but when for second time click on launch button and after close browser `exit event` is fire

Comment: You're using the _old_ version of Ionic Native, right? Because in the last version the available methods have changed a little bit ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/))

Comment: I try with new way and old way but inappbrowser event fire in second call

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the first time you click on Launch button, the device platform is not ready yet?

Try to put the calls to any `InAppBrowser` methods inside `Plaform.ready()`, like so:

```
...
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
...
export class HomePage {
    private iab: InAppBrowser;
    private platform: Platform;
    private browser;
    ...
    var launch = function(url) {
        this.platform.ready().then(
            () => {
                this.browser = this.iab.create( url, "_blank", "EnableViewPortScale=yes,closebuttoncaption=Done" );
                this.browser.on("exit").subscribe(
                    (event) => {
                        this.close_event = true;
                    },
                    (err) => {
                        console.log("InAppBrowser Loadstop Event Error: " + err);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
    };
    ...
}
```