# ionic 2 - inappbrowser "browser.on(...).subscribe is not a function" error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I follow this http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/ document for use inappbrowser and try with below steps :

1- install

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 

 npm install --save @ionic-native/in-app-browser
```

2 - Add this plugin to app.module.ts  provider

3 - add to constructor :

```
constructor(private iab: InAppBrowser) { }
```

4- and use it in launch method like this :

```
import { InAppBrowser,InAppBrowserEvent} from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';

launch(urlc){
      let url = 'https://example.com/';
      let browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank', 'location=yes');
      browser.on('loadstart').subscribe((ev: InAppBrowserEvent) => {
          this.close_status=true;
      });
  }
```

but when serve and call launch method I see this error :

```
Runtime Error
browser.on(...).subscribe is not a function
```

Comment: Did you checked it on mobile?

Comment: yes in device is worked , but when first call event not fire and when second try event is fire

Comment: after run in device throw this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327252/ionic-2-inappbrowser-event-fire-after-second-call

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`InAppBrowser` is a cordova plugin, and because of that, it's not available when running the app in the browser with `ionic serve`.

Try to run the app on a simulator / real device to use the plugin.

Comment: yes in device is worked , but when first call event not fire and when second try event is fire

Comment: after run in device throw this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44327252/ionic-2-inappbrowser-event-fire-after-second-call

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at that question, but this question is related to `browser.on(...).subscribe is not a function` so I think the answer solves that issue.

Comment: yes solved, but if  this error not related with second problem in device,that inappbrowser  worked for second call in device and simulator

Comment: Yeap, I'm taking a look at that one... let's continue in the other SO question

Comment: What do you mean by that @AlokRajasukumaran?

Comment: tried above and once I deploy in the device, it shows a window opens and closes. :(

Comment: It's hard to know what could be going on with that information only, but it must be something on your end. Please create a new question with the most relevant parts of your code, so we can take a look at it...

Answer (score 8):

If you want to avoid this error you have 3 options:

1. Run the app in a real device.
2. Run the app in an emulator.
3. Run the app in a browser, using the "Browser" platform (which is supported
   by the InAppBrowser plugin). Instead of doing:

   ionic serve

do:

```
ionic cordova run browser
```