# Ionic InAppBrowser Event Observable

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable, ionic3

I just start using ionic framework.

I use InAppBrowser plugin in my app and I need to observe the event on it.

InAppBrowser events:

1. `pageload`
2. `pagestop`
3. `pageerror`
4. `exit`

I have checked the documentation here, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser/

So, I wrote my code:

```
this.browser = this.iab.create('https://www.google.com/', '_self');
this.browser.on('pageload').subscribe(
  (next) => {
    console.log(`pageload next: ${next}`);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(`pageload error: ${error}`);
  },
  () => {
    console.log(`pageload completed`);
  }
)
```

... and it gave me error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.browser.on(...).subscribe is not a function
    at DrawPage.ionViewDidLoad (main.js:56064)
    at ViewController._lifecycle (main.js:17243)
    at ViewController._didLoad (main.js:17116)
    at NavControllerBase._didLoad (main.js:44717)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at Object.onInvoke (main.js:4427)
    at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
    at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
    at NgZone.run (main.js:4295)
    at NavControllerBase._viewAttachToDOM (main.js:44365)
```

Comment: Are you testing this on the browser? If so, check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328762/ionic-2-inappbrowser-browser-on-subscribe-is-not-a-function-error anyway, pase the output from 'ionic info' so we can check your environment, if the version of your ionic is correct.

Comment: @ChristianBenseler Yes, I test it on browser. I will try to debug it on real device, thx

Answer (score 0):

use '_blank' to access browser events pageload, pagestop, pageerror, e_self load the external page on the cordova webview, which is out of reach of your code.
ngZone can be used.

```js
const browserRef = this.iab.create(externalUrl, '_blank', options);
browserRef.on(BrowserEvent).subscribe(promise)
```