# InAppBrowser.on('loadstart').subscribe Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe')

Tags: ionic-framework

An undefined error is being thrown on the "browser.on".

```
public openWithInAppBrowser(url: string) {
    let target = "_blank";
    var browser = this.theInAppBrowser.create(url, target, this.options);

    browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
      console.log(event.url);
    });  
}
```

Constructor code contains:

```
 constructor(public storage: Storage, private router: Router, private navCtrl: NavController, private theInAppBrowser: InAppBrowser,
          private toastCtrl: ToastController)
```

Comment: Try to use device for running InAppBrowser. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case subscribe of undefined error was caused missing installed `npm install cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`.

Check https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/in-app-browser also consider this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328903/14655526.